# Check how many selects have had an options selected using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a bunch of selects:

```
<select name="paraquien" class="selectpicker form-control paraquien" id="paraquien" onchange="mostrarPreguntas();">
    <option value=""><?=__('¿Para quién es el plan?')?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></option>
    <option value="1"><?=__('Para mi')?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></option>
    <option value="2"><?=__('Para regalar')?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></option>
</select>
```

and I would like to know if all of them have been selected, and in that case trigger an event. I've tried this far:

```
jQuery('.paraquien option:selected')
```

Getting this result array:

```
[
    <option value=​"1">​Para mi ​</option>​, 
    <option value=​"1">​Hombre​</option>​, 
    <option value=​"3">​Estudiante​</option>​,
    <option value>​Su situación sentimental​</option>​,
    <option value>​¿Tiene hijos?​</option>
​]
```

You can see every option selected has a value attribute set, what I would like to know is how to get just the options which value has been already set, in the same selector mentioned before.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to check for `select` elements where the value is still `''`. Try this:

```
var $unchosenSelects = $('.paraquien').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == '';
});
if ($unchosenSelects.length) {
    // there was at least one select within nothing chosen...
}
```

Similarly you could use `map()` to get all the values in an array, then `$.inArray` to check for empty strings:

```
var chosenValues = $('.paraquien').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});
if ($.inArray(chosenValues, '') != -1) {
    // there was at least one select within nothing chosen...
}
```